Sitecore custom processor to resolve the "potentially dangerous Request.Path value"
We are getting the error A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client and we would like to add the custom Sitecore processor to resolve this issue.

You can handle it without a custom processor. Refer to ASP.NET request validation errors article.
Request validation is a feature in ASP.NET that examines an HTTP request and determines whether it contains potentially dangerous content. In this context, potentially dangerous content is any HTML markup or JavaScript code in the body, header, query string, or cookies of the request. ASP.NET performs this check because markup or code in the URL query string, cookies, or posted form values might have been added for malicious purposes.
Hope it helps!

Try creating a processor using this approach. Create a Generic Exception Handler using this code.
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Customer.Foundation.Logging.Services;

public class GenericExceptionHandler : ExceptionProcessor
{
    public override void Process(ExceptionArgs args)
    {
       // Write logic here
    }
}

Here is the patch file.
<sitecore>
    <pipelines>
        <mvc.renderRendering>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc">
                <patch:attribute name="type">CustomClassName, AssemblyName</patch:attribute>
            </processor>
        </mvc.renderRendering>
    </pipelines>        
</sitecore>

Hope this will work for you.
